# Copy sheet content from selected file to the current one

Tags: excel, vba

I need to open a "select file" dialog then copy a sheet (always same name, same position) from the selected file into the second sheet in the current Excel file.

So far the I can choose and open the file. That is where it stops. Nothing is copied and nothing is in my clipboard.

I searched and found a few not working solutions.

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub Import()

Dim VarDateiPfad As Variant
Dim Source As Workbook
Dim FilterDestination As Workbook

'You choose the starting Folder for the "Select File" Dialog
ChDrive ("X:\") 'hier Laufwerk angeben
ChDir ("X:\X....") ' hier exakten Pfad angeben

'Starts the dialog and saves the link to the file
VarDateiPfad = Application.GetOpenFilename("Exceldateien,*.xls*", 1)

Workbooks.Open Filename:=VarDateiPfad, ReadOnly:=False

'Here seems to be where the problems occur
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("X").UsedRange.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").PasteSpecial xlValues
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

This here was my last Version before fixing the issue:

```
Public Sub Import()

Dim VarDateiPfad As String
Dim FilterSource As Workbook
Dim FilterDestination As Workbook

Set FilterDestination = ActiveWorkbook

'Legt Standard Verzeichnis des "Datei öffnen" Dialogs fest.
ChDrive ("X") 'hier Laufwerk angeben
ChDir ("X") ' hier exakten Pfad angeben

'Startet "Import" Dialog und legt ausgewählte Datei in "VarDateiPfad" ab
VarDateiPfad = Application.GetOpenFilename("Exceldateien,*.xls*", 1, "X")

Set FilterSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=VarDateiPfad, ReadOnly:=False)

    FilterSource.Worksheets("X").UsedRange.Copy
        FilterDestination.Worksheets("Import").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Source.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would leave a comment but didn't have enough rep to do so, so i will leave a reply

```
FilterSource.Worksheets("X").UsedRange.Copy
FilterDestination.Worksheets("Import").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

you have copied a select range but didn't tell the macro where to paste, so this seems to be the issue

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`. Instead set the opened workbook to a variable:

```
Dim WbToImport As Workbook 
Set WbToImport = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=VarDateiPfad, ReadOnly:=False)
```

And then use the variable to access the workbook directly.

```
WbToImport.Worksheets("X").UsedRange.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
WbToImport.Close
```

With this technique it is much more reliable that the correct workbook is used to copy from, because `ActiveWorkbook` can be any workbook that is active at the moment. But that's not necessarily the workbook that you just opened.

---

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Import()    
    Dim FilterDestination As Workbook  
    Set FilterDestination = ThisWorkbook

    'Legt Standard Verzeichnis des "Datei öffnen" Dialogs fest.
    ChDrive ("X") 'hier Laufwerk angeben
    ChDir ("X") ' hier exakten Pfad angeben

    'Startet "Import" Dialog und legt ausgewählte Datei in "VarDateiPfad" ab
    Dim VarDateiPfad As String
    VarDateiPfad = Application.GetOpenFilename("Exceldateien,*.xls*", 1, "X")

    Dim FilterSource As Workbook
    Set FilterSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=VarDateiPfad, ReadOnly:=False)

    FilterSource.Worksheets("X").UsedRange.Copy
    FilterDestination.Worksheets("Import").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    FilterSource.Close
```

Comment: @G.M added an example

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

```
Public Sub Import()

    Dim VarDateiPfad As Variant
    Dim Source As Workbook
    Dim FilterDestination As Workbook

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook

    'You choose the starting Folder for the "Select File" Dialog
    ChDrive ("X:\") 'hier Laufwerk angeben
    ChDir ("X:\X....") ' hier exakten Pfad angeben

    'Starts the dialog and saves the link to the file
    VarDateiPfad = Application.GetOpenFilename("Exceldateien,*.xls*", 1)

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=VarDateiPfad, ReadOnly:=False

    'Here seems to be where the problems occur

    Sheets("X").Cells.Copy

    Source.Activate
    Sheets("Import").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False



End Sub
```

Comment: Note: It's a bad practice to use `.Activate` and you don't need it if you apply [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Also see my answer to avoid using `ActiveWorkbook` and `.Activate` which is **much** more reliable and faster. Also the OP already used `ThisWorkbook` in a good way.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It is a poor technique and it's scoffed at. On the other hand it's quick and practical,easier to understand for beginners. Cheers,

Comment: But this way beginners learn to do it a bad way. Better to teach the good way to beginners otherwise it will be hard to change their behavior.

Comment: Thank you both a lot, i added a Post with the current state of the drama ^^